# PDO ORDER BY not working on fields that are not auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * from slider WHERE page = :page ORDER BY index ASC");
$q->bindValue(':page', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$q->execute();

if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    for ($i=0; $i < $q->rowCount(); $i++) { 
        $path = $result[$i]['path'];
        echo "<div><img src=\"$path\"></div>";
    }
}
```

As is, there is no result that is being shown.
If however I order by a different field, namely 'id' which is auto increment and the primary key of the table, I do get results that are ordered by the correct field.

Comment: if there's no results, and the query didn't fail, then your `where` clause didn't match anything. so... .basic debugging: `var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` to see what you're testing with.

Comment: Use pdoException to see bdd errors ..

Comment: @MarcB Although I understand what you're saying and I understand the reasoning behind it, whenever I remove `ORDER BY index ASC` the query is executed and I do get to see the results I expect.

Comment: `index` is a mysql reserved word - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)' is a reserved word in MySQL. If you want to use it as a column name and in queries you must surround it with back ticks.

```
SELECT * from `slider` WHERE `page` = :page ORDER BY `index` ASC
```